# Remove leading "bullet" from a word document

Tags: excel, ms-word

I update a word document with an Excel macro
The Word starter has specific codes that may be preceded by a "Bullet" item (not just a period)

- CtrlRep01
- CtrlRep02
- CtrlRep03
- CtrlRep04

The above would allow for up to four entries to be replaced with new text
In case I only have two entries to be replaced, I blank out the remainder, thus the output would look like

- Newly added text line 1
- Newly added text line 2
- 
- 

How do I remove the orphaned bullet and the empty line? In the actual case there may be as many as eighty (80) CtrlRepXX entries!!

Comment: please add a link to a screen shot and some of your code which you already have. where from you have this leading bullet point?

Answer (score 0):

You select the empty lines including bullets and click on the bullet button visible on the top of tool bar in Word. Still you have issues, Kindly reply me with screen shots.